# Posts Page shows Classic Editor interface not Gutenberg

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I have an issue,

When I open Pages->Posts Page (the page which I pinned for latest posts) the classic editor interface shows up.
I can't understand should it be by default?

Because in my localhost it shows up in Gutenberg interface, but not on my hosting.
Can someone check it, please?

I have wordpress version 5.5.1. I tried to deactivate all plugins, but the same result. I haven't any errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check you don't have classic editor installed, remove completely.

try to re-install wordpress, sometimes it solves mysterious issuess.


did you tried switching themes?

Comment: I don't have classic editor installed, also I tried to change themes, tried twenty twenty but nothing changed. So it's not by default, right? You can give the answer, I will point it. @herzlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check you don't have classic editor installed, remove completely. if not,  **try to re-install wordpress**, sometimes it solves mysterious issues. did you tried switching themes?  is it a multi-site?